# Running two Android DJI apps over USB at the same time?

Tags: dji-sdk, android-open-accessory

Has anyone had success running a custom DJI Mobile SDK application alongside the DJI Go application on Android? It appears as though only one application at a time can connect to the controller over USB.

I am creating an app with the Mobile SDK for streaming video and telemetry data back to a server. I would like to connect this app to the drone while simultaneously using the DJI Go app to fly.

Is this a limitation of the Android Open Accessory Protocol?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is a limitation in AOA protocol. DJI, at the moment, is trying to find a solution for this. They may come up with it soon.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Do you happen to have an article or other source for this information that you could share?

Comment: I am also quite interested in this... I would like to create a DJI aircraft pilot sharing system. (multiple pilots) I want my primary pilot to be able to use DJI Go 4 while my sharing app runs in the background.